# Qual é a (real) utilidade da anotação javax.persistence.Transient?

Tags: java, jpa

A anotação `@Transient` serve para informar ao JPA que aquele atributo não está mapeado na tabela e/ou não deve ser persistido.

Além disso, depois que a entidade que possui atributos anotados com `@Transient` é persistida, esses atributos retornam com seus *valores padrão* (salvo os tipos primitivos, voltam com `null` e isso pode facilmente causar `NullPointerException`).

---

**A dúvida é:** por que anotar um atributo com `@Transient`?

- Se o atributo não pertence á tabela ou não deve ser persistido, não deveria ser removido da entidade?
- Há quem diga que atributos anotados com essa anotação são úteis para "carregar valores calculados", mas nesse caso, não seria melhor um método ao invés de um atributo? Ou melhor: se, novamente, esse valor calculado não pertence á tabela, não deveria ser removido da entidade e adquirido/resgatado de outra forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você já mencionou, serve para excluir um determinado valor do mapeamento do JPA e é útil no caso de atributos calculados.

Para dar um exemplo de onde isso é útil, imagine que esse valor seja algo custoso de se obter. Como exemplos desses casos, posso citar isso:

- Um valor contendo um total que tem que ser calculado ao acessar-se várias entidades espalhadas em diversas tabelas.
- O conteúdo de um arquivo lido do disco.
- Algum dado que pertence a entidade mas que não está no banco de dados, sendo obtido por meio de um webservice.

Observe que em todos esses casos, se você forçar o getter a ter que recalcular isso sempre, o desempenho será ruim. Isso poderia ocasionar múltiplas consultas a diversas tabelas no banco de dados, ou então a múltiplas leituras de um arquivo, ou talvez a múltiplas consultas a algum webservice.

Fazer essas coisas no getter não é boa ideia, sendo melhor que essas coisas todas sejam computadas no processamento da lógica de negócio da funcionalidade em questão e o getter só retorne o resultado, ainda mais que pouca gente espere que um getter seja um método com uma complexidade alta (até porque isso não costuma ser boa prática de programação).

A linguagem Java já dispõe de um modificador `transient` para fazer isso em campos, mas ele não pode ser usado para métodos, caso você esteja fazendo o mapeamento nos getters ao invés de fazê-lo nos atributos. É por isso que inventaram a anotação `@Transient`. Na verdade, o certo seria que o modificador `transient` não existisse e o seu comportamento fosse substituído por uma anotação, mas na época que ele foi concebido, não existiam anotações no Java ainda.

Quanto a questão de colocar isso na entidade e não em alguma outra classe, é porque a entidade representa um conceito do seu domínio com as suas respectivas regras de negócio. Ocorre que esses recursos que têm que ser computados fazem parte da regra de negócio da entidade modelada, e portanto, lá deveriam estar, caso contrário, isso possivelmente seria uma violação do encapsulamento.

O erro (muito comum por sinal) é acreditar-se na premissa de que a entidade deve refletir o banco de dados diretamente e imitar a sua estrutura, porém isso nem sempre é verdade. Por vezes, o formato da entidade não é exatamente o mesmo do banco de dados.

E mesmo que o formato da entidade reflita fielmente a modelagem do banco de dados, acrescentar-se na entidade `Venda`, um atributo `totalVenda` que tem o valor resultante do somatório dos valores de todos os itens da venda, não deveria ser algo a atrapalhar o mapeamento JPA.

Comment: Entendi. Era isso o que imaginava. Só não concordo com a ideia de que a entidade não deve refletir o banco, mas isso é uma opinião pessoal e não tem por que discutirmos. Obrigado pela resposta!